# Reload cart page automatically after the last item is removed

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

How do I reload cart page automatically after the last item is removed?

The below code works:

```
jQuery(function($) {
   $(document.body).on( 'wc_cart_emptied', function() {
      if ( $( '.woocommerce-cart-form' ).length === 0 ) {
         $(window.location).attr('href', '" . get_permalink() . "');
         return;
      }
   });
});
```

So I try to convert it into vanilla JavaScript, then it doesn't work already:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   document.body.addEventListener('wc_cart_emptied', function() {
      if (!document.querySelector('.woocommerce-cart-form')) {
         location.reload();
      }
   });
});
```

Anything I did it wrongly? Or is there any other alternative?

Comment: There is no obvious error. What happens when you remove the `DOMContentLoaded` event?

Comment: If I remove the DOMContentLoaded event, the page still doesn't reload. And there is no error in the console...

Comment: Well, the problem is that this is hard to test on our end without having a Woocommerce environment. I would suggest that you debug every line to see if the event is fired and if the body element captures it. Then go from there.